# How to remove diagramming support objects from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, diagram

I need to remove diagramming support tables, stored procs, views, etc from SQL Servrer using TSQL script.

Is there such a script available?

SQL 2005 and 2008.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can drop the objects, but a user will be prompted to recreate them when they click the diagrams node.

Objects:

- sp_upgraddiagrams
- sp_helpdiagrams
- sp_helpdiagramdefinition
- sp_creatediagram
- sp_renamediagram
- sp_alterdiagram
- sp_dropdiagram
- fn_diagramobjects
- sysdiagrams
- dt_properties (?)

Answer (score 41):

```
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_alterdiagram;  
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_creatediagram;  
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_dropdiagram; 
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_helpdiagramdefinition; 
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_renamediagram; 
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_upgraddiagrams; 
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_helpdiagrams;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_diagramobjects;
DROP TABLE dbo.sysdiagrams;
```

That removes all of them.  Would be nice if there was as remove diagrams references wizard like the add.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM sysdiagrams -- remove all diagram
DELETE FROM sysdiagrams WHERE name = 'yourDiagram' -- remove with condition
```