# Missing Diagram folder in Database Explorer at Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, database-design, visual-studio-2012, database-diagramming

I was in a middle of designing a website when suddenly Database Diagram folder just disappeared from the Database Explorer. I have no idea what happened and what to do right now, as I desperately need it to continue my work - adding tables to database manually are not an option for me.

I've been seeking for the solution for a whole day, and I even re-installed the Visual Studio and local IIS server, but it wasn't helpfull at all.

Is there any way to bring the feature back or at least is there any free tool that would work on Windows 8 x64 and has diagram-based database designer for MSSQL 2008?

## EDIT


It seems that Microsoft removed the diagramming for purpose. Which is pretty logical in a business logic - why would somebody buy Server Management Studio if they have basic tool (diagramming) built in Visual Studio?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is a free download. It doesn't cost anything any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Database Diagram is a feature of SQL Server, not Visual Studio. I am not sure what VS uses to display that folder but you might want to verify with your DBA or check the configuration of the database to see if someone has not just [disabled the ability to use diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525610/how-to-remove-diagramming-support-objects-from-sql-server). Have you tried refreshing your connection to the database server as well?

2) How is adding tables to a database manually not an option? If you get yourself dependent on doing things one way and only that one way you are setting yourself up for disaster in future projects, as you are in your current one. There are other ways from within VS to create a table, it just may not be a graphical picture that diagrams offers.

3) Have you looked at the database through SSMS to see if the diagrams folder shows up there?

Comment: 1) I installed VS 2010 nest to my 2012 and Database Diagrams folder is visible there - I think I'll just modify my DB by the older version

2) The DB structure is very complicated with many foreign keys, I have limited time and sadly I have to see te diagram to be sure it'a all connected properly...

3) I can't install SSMS on Win 8 due to various errors during installation.

Well, installing VS 2010 somehow solved my problem, but I still have no idea why the folder is missing.

Comment: Same problem also ! Simply not exist on VS2012

Comment: Same problem here! I installed SSMS 2012 express edition to be able to design my DB using DB diagram

Comment: Apparently, VS 2012 does not support DB diagrams by design according to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/34154fdf-d81c-4d58-abf4-c27b157dd420)

Comment: It was was working for me with Sql-Server 2008 and VS2012 pro, When I upgraded to Sql-Server 2012; The diagram folder disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Hello this has been my solution that worked for me and enabled me to use database diagram ide in visual studio 2012!!

First i installed SQL Server Management Studio. I then noticed that i still did not have SQLEXPRESS Service or SQL Agent Browser in my computer services either.. This was why i assume i couldn't login to any of the SSMS which was annoying.  I then downloaded SQL Server Express R2 which then ran me though another setup which was fine. I did also choose to put a sql server password for SQL Server Express.

Once installed I double checked to make sure the services where running by right clicking MY COMPUTER / MANAGE / SERVICES -- scroll down till you see "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" and make sure that the service has started and also "SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS)" (this one was turned off when i checked) .. i was then able to login to SSMS without a problem.

I then created a new database, right clicked diagram like we always do in VS and created a diagram with two tables, created their relationships blah blah..

i then created a new website in vs 2012, i clicked "Connect To Database" in the SERVER EXPLORER"

I choose my server name, used windows authenication and selected the database i just created in SSMS.

Then to my suprise i now have database diagram designing in Visual Studio 2012.. Finally!

Thankyou microsoft for removing such a cool feature which now gives us developers a few things to do.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I installed  the Sql Express (free) and the management system (free)
and attached my database from the visual studio .. WORKED LIKE A CHARM ! thanks